# finding diameter of graph

Tags: graph-theory

let us consider following graph

[image]

definition of diameter of graphs  in book  is defined  as follow :  **The diameter of G, written diam(G), is the maximum distance between any two points in G.**

now  in our case   in order to find diam(G) , let take  any two point A and H,  maximum distance between A and H  are   5  because if we use path 
A  B  C  D  E H  , but book says that diam(G)=3 why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when they say the 'maximum distance' between two points, they mean you choose $(x,y)$, find $d(x,y)$ which is the minimum length of the path between them, and then define the diameter $d_G=\sup_{x,y\in V(G)}d(x,y)$. That will give you $3$ here and not $5$. You see, the distance itself is already defined as the minimum path length, so you cannot change that. What you can do is find the maximum of this minimum over all pairs of points.

Comment: ahaa  about distance right , i understood  now